# 'hasOwnProperty' is not a function. Что не так?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Пытаюсь выявить наличие определенного параметра в url:

```
// https://localhost/?_escaped_fragment_=&dima=fil
query = url.parse(options.url, true).query;

if (query && query.hasOwnProperty('_escaped_fragment_')) {
  return true;
}
```

Но возникает ошибка: `hasOwnProperty is not a function`. Что не так?

Если вывести в консоль, то вот что:

```
console.log(query.dima); // fil
console.log(query); //  [Object: null prototype] { _escaped_fragment_: '', dima: 'fil' }
```

Comment: а на какую строчку указывает ошибка?

Comment: в коде, который приложили на `hasOwnProperty` нет и намека

Comment: @ ThisMan, да, не то вставил по ошибке. На строку где query.hasOwnProperty

Comment: что такое `url` в данном коде?

Comment: @Grundy, const url = require('url');  Может это связано с тем что на сервер два запрса, и первый запрос идёт за favocon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) определен в [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Если же проверить прототип объекта `query` можно заметить, что его значение `null`. Именно поэтому и происходит ошибка.

Для решения можно либо воспользоваться скобочной нотацией и проверять на `undefined`/`null`

либо применять `.hasOwnProperty` непосредственно из `Object.prototype`

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(query, propName)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!))

Comment: Учитывая, что прототип там специально null можно просто проверять `'_escaped_fragment_' in query` или `query._escaped_fragment_ !== undefined`